# how to call array filter within ractivejs template

Tags: ractivejs

So I don't want to use data functions (let's say I want the final user to only interact with templates and not hardcode javascript.)
If I had this array with *n* elements how can I filter it so i can get *m* elements within ractive template ? right now I have this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/t168vymw/4/) >> http://jsfiddle.net/t168vymw/4/ which is not working correctly.

requirements: 
I cannot use some function to filter, like 

`data: {filtersomething: function(){...} }`

but instead, let the user play with complex array function convertions from the template.
Is ractive yet supporting this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ractive doesn't support anything that involves `function` keyword inside expressions, but there are 3 ways to do this:

- data functions,
- method calls (calling methods of the ractive instance from inside the template),
- filtering data directly in the template.

You said you want all the logic to be in the template so that leaves us with the option #3. For example, if you wanted to display only even numbers from the list, you could do this:

```
{{ #a }}
    {{ #!(this % 2) }}
        {{ this }}
    {{/}}
{{ /a }}
```

However, this is usually considered an anti-pattern. It's probably a better idea to allow the user to write custom JS or to provide them with some prepared functions they can use in the template.

Comment: I know is an antipattern, and it's kinf of ugly to have javascript in template, but it's a requirement to keep the user away from the js code. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open it up to arbitrary js from the user, then you could do something like this (http://jsfiddle.net/h7ut7cbx/2/):

```
<input value='{{filter}}'>
<br>
{{# filtered }}
    {{.}}<br>
{{/ }}
```

and

```
data: {
    a: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    filter: 'b%2'
},
computed: {
    filtered: function(a, filter){
        var fn = new Function('b', 'return ' + (this.get('filter')||'true') + ';')
        return this.get('a').filter(fn)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an ideal solution, but user cannot edit Ractive js instance. thanks for help

Comment: They don't need to. `filter: 'b%2'` just a default. Or am I missing something?